# How to make an edge thicker?

Tags: python

I tried to use solidify modifier but it does not work.

```
verts = [
(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 10),
]

edges = [
    (0, 1),
]

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Edge")
me.from_pydata(verts, edges, [])
edge = bpy.data.objects.new("Edge", me)
edge.name='myedge'
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(edge)
```

Comment: Require a face to solidify

Comment: That is it!Thanks!!!How to implement EdgetoTube in AN by python?

Comment: Consider creating a curve instead.  Remember when answering previous question (code above) trying to use a skin modifier, didn't work when moving verts via handler. Did have both verts at same location to start which the modifier doesn't like.  A beveled and tapered curve may be an option to consider.

Comment: @batFINGER That is it!Thanks!